# 2 variable recursion relation

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following 2-variable recursion relation.
The initial conditions are e(1,0) = 1, and also e(s,r) = 0 for $s < 1$ or
$s > 2r+1$.  The general recursion relation is

$e(s,r+1) = e(s-2,r) - (2s-1)e(s-1,r) + s^{2}e(s,r)$

I have been able to find without too much difficulty $e(2r+1,r) = 1$,
$e(2r,r) = -(2r^{2}-3r+4$), $e(2,r) = 1 - 4^{r}$, and $e(1,r) = 1$.
The only way I know how to determine the general "middle" coefficients is to guess
a form for the solution and solve accordingly; however, I have not found a suitable functional
form that changes between a polynomial in $r$ and exponential functions in $r$ as $s$
ranges over its allowed values.  Any suggestions on how to solve this recursion
relation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first few rows of $e(s,r)$, with $s$ in the horizontal direction starting
at 1 and $r$ in the vertical direction starting at 0 are

1

1  -3  1

1  -15  25  -10  1

1  -63  301  -350  140  -21  1

Looking at these rows in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences yielded
that the absolute values of these numbers appeared to be Stirling numbers of the
second kind.  Specifically, $e(s,r) = (-1)^{s+1} S(2r+1, s)$.

```
 To prove this, consider the basic recursion relation for $S(n,k)$,
```

namely $S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + kS(n-1,k)$.  Using this recursion relation on
the two terms on the right hand side yields

$S(n,k) = S(n-2,k-2) + (2k-1)S(n-2,k-1) + k^{2}S(n-2,k)$

Setting $s = k$ and $n = 2r+1$ and putting the $S$ in terms of $e$ yields

$e(s,r+1) = e(s-2,r) - (2s-1)e(s-1,r) + s^{2}e(s,r)$,

which, when combined with the initial conditions, is what we wanted to prove.